# Get the index row number kendo grid angular component http://plnkr.co/edit/KbJ3zAgSEN1AGWUj4dsu?p=preview

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Need to add .prodDiscontinued class to kendo-grid when "Discontinued": true(json from products.ts).

Comment: What’s the issue? Your question is hard to follow

Comment: I am unable to get $index of row from kendo grid. So that I can add a class prodDiscontinued to the entire row where the current row has a key value pair discontinued: true from products.ts